# Type error:unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, machine-learning

I got this error:
    unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
and here is my code:

```
 Lambda = [0,0.001,0.003,0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1,3,10]
    J=[]
    for i in range(10):
         poly_theta,poly_J = gradientDes(X_poly,y,np.zeros((X_poly.shape[1],1)),20000,0.01,Lambda[i])
         J_val = costFunction(X_poly_val,yval,poly_theta,Lambda[i])[0]
         J.append(J_val)
```

And in the logs I'm getting:

```
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-c687e5ea36d2> in <module>
      3 for i in range(10):
      4     l = float(Lambda[i])
----> 5     poly_theta,poly_J = gradientDes(X_poly,y,np.zeros((X_poly.shape[1],1)),20000,0.01,l)
      6     J_val = costFunction(X_poly_val,yval,poly_theta,l)[0]
      7     J.append(J_val)

<ipython-input-7-f608ab80e105> in gradientDes(X, y, theta, num_iter, alpha, Labda)
      5     for i in range(num_iter):
      6 
----> 7         cost,grad = costFunction(X,y,theta,Lambda)
      8         theta = theta - (alpha*grad)
      9         J_hist.append(cost)

<ipython-input-5-51aca0d972a7> in costFunction(X, y, theta, Lambda)
      6     cost = 1/(2*m)*np.sum(err**2)
      7 
----> 8     reg_cost = cost + (Lambda/(2*m))*np.sum(theta[1:]**2)
      9 
     10 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

I want cost of validation set for each value in Lambda and see which value gives the least cost.
Here is the code for cost function :

```
def costFunction(X,y,theta,Lambda):

    m = X.shape[0]
    pred =  X @ theta
    err = pred - y
    cost = 1/(2*m)*np.sum(err**2)

    reg_cost = cost + (Lambda/(2*m))*np.sum(theta[1:]**2)


    grad_0 = (1/m)*(X.T @ (pred-y))
    grad_1 = (1/m)*(X.T @ (pred-y)) + (Lambda/m)*(theta)
    grad = np.vstack((grad_0[0],grad_1[1:]))

    return reg_cost,grad
```

This is for Gradient descent:

```
def gradientDes(X,y,theta,num_iter,alpha,Lambda):

    J_hist = []

    for i in range(num_iter):

        cost,grad = costFunction(X,y,theta,Lambda)
        theta = theta - (alpha*grad)
        J_hist.append(cost)

    return theta,J_hist
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Please show your `gradientDes` & `costFunction` functions.

Comment: `lambda` is a keyword.  Using that as a variable name could also be causing issues.

Comment: Lambda is a `list`, if you want to use element wise operations change it to ndarray. `Lambda = np.array([0,0.001,0.003,0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1,3,10])`

Comment: @Rishitha, You have provided insufficient information with respect to code. Can you also add `gradientDes()` and `costFunction()` functions. So that I can look into that. Thanks

Comment: Note also that there is a type in the gradient function -- it takes `Labda` as argument so in reality you are probably accidentally using a globally defined `Lambda` in the function. But this is just speculation as long as the full code isn't provided.